# Programmatically highlight first row in tableview after first load

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, row, highlight

Im trying to highlight the first row in my table upon first loading the data and just cannot get it to work!

I have tried lots of ways with no joy, the latest attempt being this:

```
NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0,1};

NSIndexPath *n = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:n atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:n animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

you should probably do this after your view has appeared.